# Local variable and state variable, and the difference between them

Tags: solidity, contract-development, state-variable, local-variables

I am new  to solidity. When I read the [solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#types), it says *local variable* and *state variable*. But I can't find the definition of the two terms.

Can anyone explain the meaning of local variable and state variable, and the difference between them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**State Variables**

From the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/structure-of-a-contract.html#state-variables),

> State variables are values which are permanently stored in contract
>   storage.

and can be declared in a contract as follow,

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData; // State variable
    // ...
}
```

**Local variables**

Carries the usual meaning, that their context is within a function and cannot be accessed outside. Usually these are the variables that we create temporarily to hold values in calculating or processing something. Local variables (of struct, array or mapping) reference storage as pointed out [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do), local variable will act as an alias for pre-existing one in the storage. Check the example quoted below to understand what happens.

> A common mistake is to declare a local variable and assume that it
>   will be created in memory, although it will be created in storage:
>
> ```
> /// THIS CONTRACT CONTAINS AN ERROR
>
>
>
>  pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
>     contract C {
>         uint someVariable;
>         uint[] data;
>
>         function f() {
>             uint[] x;
>             x.push(2);
>             data = x;
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> The type of the local variable x is uint[] storage, but since storage
>   is not dynamically allocated, it has to be assigned from a state
>   variable before it can be used. So no space in storage will be
>   allocated for x, **but instead it functions only as an alias for a
>   pre-existing variable in storage**.
>
> What will happen is that the compiler interprets x as a storage
>   pointer and will make it point to the storage slot 0 by default. This
>   has the effect that someVariable (which resides at storage slot 0) is
>   modified by x.push(2).
>
> The correct way to do this is the following:
>
> ```
> pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
>     contract C {
>         uint someVariable;
>         uint[] data;
>
>         function f() {
>             uint[] x = data;
>             x.push(2);
>         }
>     }
> ```

**Defaults for the storage location**

Here are defaults for the storage location depending on which type of variable it concerns ([source](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do)):

> - state variables are always in storage
> - function arguments are in memory by default
> - local variables of struct, array or mapping type reference storage by    default
> - local variables of value type (i.e. neither array, nor struct nor       mapping) are stored in the stack

Comment: I am confused that local variables always reference storage. As you mentioned that   _Usually these are the variables that we create temporarily to hold values in calculating or processing something_ . I don't think I need reference storage. Can you explain the relationship between local variables and storage/memory variables? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated the answer, check whether it's clear to you now

Comment: Storage/Memory/Stack variable is the physical concept, and Local/State variable is the logical concept. Is it right?

Comment: Storage, Memory, stack is the place where the variable is stored, Local/State defines both scope and the place in solidity

Answer (score 2):

*in simple terms:* is all about the scopes

we consider as states all variables defined outside the scope of the defined functions (we can consider them as global variables) whereas local variables are the rest: function arguments and variables declared within functions scope. as you know  Each method has its own entirely new scope.

Per design, states as permanently stored in the contract's storage

Comment: There is some confusion, as you shown here, local variables stored in Memory whereas the documentation of Solidity stated that `(default for local variables is storage and the location is forced to storage for state variables)` https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#data-location